# move vertices of nurbs relatively to neighboring vertices

Tags: nurbs-surface

Is it not possible to move vertices relative to each other in when editing the nurbs curve? When I select a vertex, the neighboring ones tend to follow it, i would like to avoid this. See attached gif.[image]

Comment: This never happens with me, unless I turned proportional editing on.

Comment: From the circle that appears when you click and drag, I suspect that proportional editing is turned on as @thelabcat says.

Comment: I see that there is proportional editng in the move tool and at the top of the window (proportional edit mode). This latter option unchecked now works for me. The former option in the move tool seems to have no influence...thanks